# Custom user control in WPF with data binding

Tags: wpf, binding, user-controls

I want a custom WPF user control with one attribute/property, and implementers of that user control must be able to bind their value to it.

See this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42203/How-to-Implement-a-DependencyProperty

Instead of `<local:MyUserControl Caption="My First Dependency Property Example" />` I want something like `<local:MyUserControl Caption="{Binding MyCaption}" />` where `MyCaption` is a string property in the DataContext viewmodel class. However, whenever I change the `MyCaption` value, it is not reflected in the user control...

I've got this own piece of code where I test the same principle, but the text is never updated:

**MainWindow.xaml.cs:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private string _MyFirstName;
        public string MyFirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return _MyFirstName;
            }
            set
            {
                _MyFirstName = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyFirstName");
            }
        }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            //this.Klaas.SetValue(NameControl.FirstNameProperty, "Mike");
            MyFirstName = "Mike";
        }
    }
}
```

**MainWindow.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:me="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525"
        DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <me:NameControl x:Name="Klaas" FirstName="{Binding MyFirstName}" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Button Grid.Row="1" Click="Button_Click">Pick a name</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**NameControl.xaml.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NameControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class NameControl : UserControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty FirstNameProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "FirstName", 
            typeof(string),
            typeof(NameControl),
            new PropertyMetadata("NoName", OnFirstNamePropertyChanged));

        public string FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return (string)GetValue(FirstNameProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(FirstNameProperty, value);
            }
        }

        private static void OnFirstNamePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            NameControl source = d as NameControl;
            // Do something...
        }

        public NameControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

**NameControl.xaml**

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.NameControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Text="{Binding FirstName}" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Text="{Binding LastName}" />
</Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do

```
<UserControl ... DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

you effectively overwrite `DataContext` that would normally be passed to your control from visual tree and you change binding context for bindings within `NameControl` control. I would suggest to remove that and do that per binding

```
<TextBlock ... Text="{Binding FirstName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
<TextBlock ... Text="{Binding LastName, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
```

or to make it simpler give `UserControl` some name and use it for bindings within your control

```
<UserControl... x:Name="myUserControl">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Width="100" Text="{Binding FirstName, ElementName=myUserControl}" />
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Width="100" Text="{Binding LastName, ElementName=myUserControl}" />
   </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Yesss, now it works! Thanks so much. UK saved my day!